# Spring data elasticsearch fails to initialze the elasticsearchtemplate

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch 2.0.0 RELEASE and ElasticSearch 2.2.0

I have setup my beans as follows:

```
@Configuration    
public class ElasticSearchClient {
        @Autowired
        private ElasticSerachConfig esConfig;
        static final String COLON = ":";
        static final String COMMA = ",";

        private Settings getSettings(){
                return Settings.builder()                                
                                .put("client.transport.sniff", esConfig.isClusterSniff())
                                .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", esConfig.getClientPingTimeout())
                                .put("client.transport.nodes_sampler_interval", esConfig.getClientNodesSampleInterval())
                                .build();
        }

        protected Client buildClient() throws Exception {
                TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(getSettings()).build();

                for (String clusterNode : split(esConfig.getClusteNodes(), COMMA)) {
                        String hostName = substringBeforeLast(clusterNode, COLON);
                        String port = substringAfterLast(clusterNode, COLON);        

                        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostName), Integer.valueOf(port)));
                }
                client.connectedNodes();

                return client;
        }

        @Bean
        public ElasticsearchTemplate getElasticSearchTenplate() throws Exception{
                        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(buildClient());
        }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.registerDefaultValues(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:69) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.doVisitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:57) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.doVisitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:67) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:48) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:642) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:279) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

I have the following in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:2.0.0.RELEASE'      
compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:1.4.1.RELEASE'
```

Is there anything I am missing? I am pretty much following the same example as provided in the spring-data-elasticsearch example.

Comment: I am using spring-data-elasticsearch 2.0.1.RELEASE, spring-data-commons 1.12.1, and elasticsearch 2.2. I have been successful in connecting to an ES instance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring data has not been updated to 2.x series.

**UPDATE**: well. it has!

Comment: Thanks! In the spring-data-elasticsearch github page the compatibility matrix seems to indicate the version 2.0.0.RELEASE is supported for elasticsearch 2.2. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch#quick-start